# Is there any reason not to move data from one table to another using a Flyway SQL script?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kotlin, flyway, data-migration

There are two tables in my project:

**Legacy table**

| col id | col B | col C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | z |
| a | b | c |

**New table** (slightly different schema)

| col id | col B | another col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | bla |

As you can see, the legacy table has some data that the new table does not. This is because the code only recently started populating the new table. As a result, I have a task to move data from the legacy table to the new table where the old record's id is not present.

My app is a simple Spring Boot Kotlin API, with Postgres DB technology using Flyway.

My question is: Could an extra Flyway script to handle this data migration cause any technical issues? I have seen Flyway SQL scripts used to construct/alter the schema, but haven't seen them applied to actually move data from one table to another. Is there any reason not to do this?

Comment: A bit of feedback as to why my question is getting downvoted would be great.

Comment: Hello Johnny, I am not the one who downvoted so I cannot give you feedback as to why they did that. However, I can highlight some issues in your question:

Your title, "A silly question about data migration on Kotlin Springboot Postgres Flyway project", is vague. Perhaps thinking of SO as a platform to help other people aside from yourself might help you see why: In the future, if I encounter the issue described in your question, the likelihood of me searching for "A silly question about data migration on Kotlin Springboot Postgres Flyway project" is quite low.

Comment: Next some might consider your question not clear enough, for example "where there are gaps." statement is not clear, what are those gaps? Also "Could an extra flyway script to handle this 'data' migration cause any 'technical' issues?" what kind of flyway script are you talking about? What are those "technical' issues" you're worried about? All of this make the question a bit unclear.

Comment: Finally, some might consider this question coming from lack of research or effort to read the documentation. (I personally, don't believe so and cannot conclude that for as long as this question is not clear enough)

Comment: post updated based on above comments, thanks

Comment: No one can know. Flyway logs something that might not from my point, but it could be a problem for you. Also, flyway can handle all the migration without any issue and you might need something else or flyway will have problem with actually data because your table have a character that flyway cannot handle.

Comment: Thanks Umut TEKIN. Let me qualify my question by adding that flyway runs the migration script without issue 'locally'. As I said, I (in my limited experience) I have never seen flyway used to 'move' data from one table to another. Is this considered bad practice to use a tool like a flyway to achieve this, and if so, why?

Comment: There is one senario where i could be a problem. If you af timeout restrictions in your deployment process. This can cause trouble. But that heavily depends on your setup.

Comment: 'but haven't seen them applied to actually move data from one table to another' - well, this might be because it is rather unusual to maintain two tables with the same purpose, which is why usually, the Flyway migration would involve adapting an existing table to the new schema, rather than copying data between tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Flyway to move data is considered a suitable practice. In fact, Flyway is well-suited for this purpose, as long as the scripts are carefully crafted and there are no other factors outside the scope of the original question that would prevent the data from being moved.

When compared to complex data operations I have encountered in the past, moving data without any further transformations appears relatively straightforward.

Flyway scripts have broad applicability, including tasks such as data population, data removal, data updates, and schema operations. These operations may involve adding or removing columns, changing data types, or creating and deleting tables. Often, these tasks are interconnected, with actions like adding a new column requiring the population of data in that column, which may involve querying existing data.

Answer (score 1):

While the existing answer talks about the technical feasibility, perhaps an operational perspective will be useful as well.

In my experience, what works best is to ensure that each table data has a **single source of change**, i.e. one process/entity responsible for any data alterations. Mixing batch/deployment-time processes with manual 'interventions' in particular is a bone of contention I try to avoid at all costs.

The practical implication is that DB migrations should only deal with:

- Structural changes to the schema
- Changes to data in dictionary tables, to which no admin interface has been provided

And if I were to make the decision whether a Flyway script is suitable in a given scenario, I would ask myself whether the scenario is one of the above.

Now, back to the scenario at hand, you mention that

> This is because the code only recently started populating the new table.

implying that this is really an operational table, which is being actively modified by the application. This would tell me that (1) the scenario absolutely does *not* fall under one of the categories I mention, and (2) the possibility of conflicts between the migrated and the current data is so great that I would never, *ever in my life* trust an automated process alone to handle the migration correctly without any supervision. Especially if that script runs as part of the deployment process, which could be run at someone else's whim.

In this answer I'm of course making some assumptions about how your organization runs so please take it with a grain of salt. Your mileage may vary.